# Windows 10 error 0x80080005: cannot update, cannot turn on antivirus, firewall,

Tags: security, windows-update, anti-virus, windows-firewall

It's been a month since I could last update my operating system. I have Windows 10 that came with my laptop HP ZBook 17 G5. I also have HP Client Security, HP Velocity, HP WorkWise, Intel management and security status, HP Sure click installed by default. I have encountered no problems during my use of the laptop, except that updates and Windows Defender are completely disabled.

When I try to update, I get this message: There were some problems installing updates, but we’ll try again later. If you keep seeing this and want to search the web or contact support for information, this may help: (0x80080005)
[image]

I noticed also that my antivirus is turned off, and most alarmingly, I cannot turn it on or scan my computer. I have administrator rights, I am the only user of my laptop, but it says "This setting is managed by your administrator".
[image]
[image]

I've searched the net for solutions, but couldn't resolve the issue. If I run command prompt as admin and run `sfc/scannow`:
[image]

If I run Registry Editor as admin, this is what I see:
[image]
[image]

If I press the windows key+R and run services.msc, under Windows Defender, if I press Start, I get:[image]

@Ramhound If in admin CMD I run `winver`, I get:
[image]
But in Windows Update, I cannot even check what the last installed update was, if I press "View update history", the app freezes.

I really hope noone hijacked my system. Please help :(

Comment: @Didier - The issue described in those articles does not match the behavior of the author.  Windows Defender on the author's system is not currently providing Real-Time protection, while they make no mention, if Windows Defender is able or unable to perform a manual scan.  Furthermore, the article that describes the fix is confusing, it indicates you should enable network scanning but the command seems to disable it. The fact an external resource is confusing is the reason, link only answers, are typically not helpful. *The command requires understanding the default value for a bool is true.*

Comment: @Didier - It's also important to point out this particular issue that you describe was already resolved with KB4052623.

Comment: @Leo - Please edit your question to indicate that last cumaltive update your system actually installed.  You should also indicate that exact build you are current running, you can determine that information, by running `winver`.  This information is vital for us to diagnose the problem preventing your system from getting updates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105961/discussion-between-leo-and-didier).

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has released KB4052623 to solve the issue of Windows Defender not working correctly, if at all.

For those who can't install it automatically via Windows Update, they can get it here: https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4052623

Comment: Thank you for your effort! In your link, for each of the three updates, I downloaded all 3 exe files and opened them. Two of them opened, but did nothing (no window opened, nothing happened), and the third exe said "This app can't run on your PC".

Comment: @Leo - You were only suppose to download the one of those files.  The only update that should have been installed was the one released on March 24th 2020.  You can verify if it was installed by looking at your Add/Remove Programs.  You can also check to see what version of Windows Defender is running. I wouldn't expect any sort of progress and indication the patch was installed.  *I must reiterate the fact, the bug fixed by that patch, is not the actually source of your problem.*

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found a solution that worked for me. Follow the link I have given below and do a repair install with the new .iso file for Windows you would get using Windows Media Creation tool. A repair install fixed my problem and updated the windows defender. After that, you can use Windows Update to update things that haven't been updated by the new .iso file.
Note: Repair install preserves your files and apps. So you don't have to worry about losing files.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/error-there-were-some-problems-installing-updates/c169f41a-d795-495f-bfa6-dc99d1f756b1